# Extend X11 session with screens from other computers by network. Xdmx or other way

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg, xdmx

Is it possible to attach Xdmx displays to running X11 session, as new xinerama screens? It always starts new session, but I have already 4 monitors on my GPU and want to attach 3 more computers with more screens.
My X11 session is running always, I have bunch of open programs, and my uptime is usually not less than 30-60 days, so I don't want to close anything of it and restart/start new X11 sessions, especially if some backend screens becomes unavailable or unstable.

I want to see new Xdmx screens in KDE's screen management in control panel, and if it goes offline, just remove it. Is it possible somehow to add network screens as usual gpu screens?

Comment: x2x may allow you to do this. It does allow movign an application window from one X server to another on a remote box.

Comment: Sorry, I read everything about x2x, and everywhere is written about moving keyboard and mouse between X servers, not the windows. Man page have no option about this.

Comment: @Ural did you find a solution for your described problem in the OP?